# Spring MVC produces "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object exception for bean name 'command' available as request attribute"

Tags: java, spring-mvc

For some reason I cannot seem to fix this issue, even after looking at multiple examples on here.

My controller produces this error: "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object exception for bean name 'command' available as request attribute".

Here is my controller:

```
package net.codejava.Spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView visitHome() {

        return new ModelAndView("param","command",new params());
        //return new ModelAndView("index");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/HelloWorld/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView visitAdmin() {
        JasperToPDF.generate();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("main");
        model.addObject("title", "Main Page");
        model.addObject("message", "You are on the main page.");

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/HelloWorld/summary", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView visitSummary() {

                 return new ModelAndView("param","command",new params());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/HelloWorld/Detailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView visitSummary() {
        return new ModelAndView("Detailed");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/HelloWorld/generated", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String generateSummary(@ModelAttribute("command")params param, ModelMap model)
    {
                System.out.println(param.getSD());
                return ("generated");
    }
}
```

Here is my summary.jsp:

```
 <%@ page language="java" session="true" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@include file='template.jsp'%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<title>Summary</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form action="/HelloWorld/generated.jsp" method="post" commandName="command">
<form:select class="form-control" path="dept" commandName="command">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Select Department</option>
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="2">HR</option>
    <option value="3">IT</option>
    <option value="4">Security</option>
</form:select>
</br></br></br></br>

<div class="form-group">
  <form:label for="usr" path="sd">Starting date(dd-mm-yyyy):</form:label>
  <form:input type="text" path="sd" class="form-control" id="usr"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <form:label for="usr" path="sd">Ending date(dd-mm-yyyy):</form:label>
  <form:input type="text" path="ed" class="form-control" id="usr"/>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Report</button>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Spring Security Basic XML</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param> 

    <!-- Spring Security  Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: @ModelAttribute("command")params param..what is params?? is it a class...and for which request it's giving error??

Comment: params is a class, its giving this error "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute" whenever i try to access summary.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Your `summary.jsp` contains `command` as `commandName` for `form`.So before accessing it you have to call a request which gives you a bean object with name `command`.

In your code if `HelloWorld/summary` is the request to access the `summary.jsp` then in `ModelAndView` you have to mention `view` name as `summary` not `command`.

```
return new ModelAndView("summary","command",new Params());
```

**Summary.jsp**

```
<form:form action="/HelloWorld/generated.jsp" method="post" commandName="command">
 <form:select class="form-control" path="dept">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Select Department</option>
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="2">HR</option>
    <option value="3">IT</option>
    <option value="4">Security</option>
</form:select>
</br></br></br></br>

<div class="form-group">
  <form:label for="usr" path="sd">Starting date(dd-mm-yyyy):</form:label>
  <form:input type="text" path="sd" class="form-control" id="usr"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <form:label for="usr" path="sd">Ending date(dd-mm-yyyy):</form:label>
  <form:input type="text" path="ed" class="form-control" id="usr"/>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Report</button>
```

**Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/HelloWorld/Summary", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView visitSummary() {
        return new ModelAndView("Summary","command",new Params());
    }
```

**Params.java**

```
private String sd;
private String dept;
private String ed;
//getter setter
```

And URL: `localhost:****/Helloworld/Summary`

**UPDATE**

So you can see no `*.jsp` in URL it's because you have mapped only `/` in servlet mapping.

```
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Which says `DispatcherServlet` will come into picture only for `/requests`,if request includes `path info` in it then it wont reach your `request mapping`.

So either you change pattern to `/**` or `/*.jsp` or change the way of accessing.

Comment: Error is still there

Comment: What error you are getting?? how you are giving url??

Comment: this is the exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute" when i try to access "http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/summary.jsp"

Comment: Don't include `.jsp` in URL...Give the url as mentioned in answer...check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a page containing a form with commandName you have to provide a empty representation of the form. So whenever you load summary.jsp, you will have to provide the params object to the model.

params class should have all the form attributes as properties with getters and setters.

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/HelloWorld/summary", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView visitSummary() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("command", new params());
        model.setViewName("summary");
        return model;
    }
```

Also I noticed that you have written

```
<form:select class="form-control" path="dept" commandName="command">
```

I don't know if it is valid to give a commandName to select, but surely it shouldn't be named the same as the form commandName.

**Side Note:** Class names should start with uppercase letter and must be a noun.

Comment: i am getting the same error even after changing the function accoring to you @wapsa

Comment: try removing the commandName from <form:select>, Also can you post the params class in the question.